# Silverlight: DataGrid.SelectedIndex always getting -1

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid

I have this DataGrid in my project:

```
<sdk:DataGrid  RowDetailsVisibilityChanged="dataGrid1_RowDetailsVisibilityChanged" Grid.Row="1"  Loaded="dataGrid1_Loaded" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=getVarede_ResultDomainDataSource, 
                          Path=Data}" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}" Height="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" 
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionChanged="dataGrid1_SelectionChanged" 
                          MouseEnter="dataGrid1_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="dataGrid1_MouseLeave" GotFocus="dataGrid1_GotFocus" LoadingRow="dataGrid1_LoadingRow" 
                          KeyDown="dataGrid1_KeyDown" KeyUp="dataGrid1_KeyUp" LoadingRowDetails="dataGrid1_LoadingRowDetails" Cursor="Hand" Background="#FFCADCE8"  >
                //....


</sdk:DataGrid>
```

I save selected row value inside something like session:

```
private void dataGrid1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.Host.InitParams["CurrentRow"] = dataGrid1.SelectedIndex.ToString();
    //...
}
```

So when DataGrid loads I want to set stored value to SeletedIndex:

```
dataGrid1.SelectedIndex = int.Parse(Application.Current.Host.InitParams["CurrentRow"]);
```

But it always getting -1 and first row get selected.
Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot save Init params between sessions with the approach you posted.
Here is [an article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189004%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) describing how you can read the init params and store them in the isolated storage.
They are not supposed to be set by your code like you did here:

```
Application.Current.Host.InitParams["CurrentRow"] = dataGrid1.SelectedIndex.ToString();
```

[Edit]
Ok, after I read your latest comment... It dawns on me what your actual problem is. You set the `SelectedIndex` way too early. When you set it in the `Loaded` event handler the items are not there. so you can set the index to whatever you want as long as you don't have any items in the control it will always fall back to -1. you have to wait till the items are loaded and set the selected index only then.
Pseudocode ahead:

```
    ...
    INotifyCollectionChanged items = dataGrid.Items;
    items.CollectionChanged += OnItemsChanged;
    ...

private void OnItemsChanged()
{
    dataGrid.SelectedIndex = 42;
}
```

Comment: The problem isn't about Init params, If I set `dataGrid1.SelectedIndex` to for example `2`, it also gets `-1`.

Comment: @SirwanAfifi: Sounds like you set the index too early. See my edited answer.